# ActionListener and event.getSource()

Tags: java

I'm having a constant problem in Java code.
Whenever I try to use my buttons on my program they don't work and I think that the problem is at the event.getSource() but I can't find it.
Here is my complete code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*; 

public class Safe extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;
    private JTextField display;
    private JLabel displayLabel;
    private int[] pass = new int[5];
    private int hits = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Safe frame = new Safe();
        frame.setSize(250, 100);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        b1 = new JButton("1");
        window.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        b2 = new JButton("2");
        window.add(b2);
        b2.addActionListener(this);

        b3 = new JButton("3");
        window.add(b3);
        b3.addActionListener(this);

        displayLabel = new JLabel("Enter 6 digit combination:");
        window.add(displayLabel);

        display = new JTextField(6);
        window.add(display);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        int i;
        int[] user = new int[5];
        if(hits == 0){
            pass[0] = 1;
            pass[1] = 1;
            pass[2] = 1;
            pass[3] = 1;
            pass[4] = 1;
            pass[5] = 2;
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            if(event.getSource() == b1){
                display.setText("1");
                user[i] = 1;
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == b2){
                display.setText("2");
                user[i] = 2;
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == b3){
                display.setText("3");
                user[i] = 3;
            }
        }
        i = -1;
        do{
            i++;
            if(pass[i] != user[i]){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Code! Try Again!");
            }

            if(i == 5){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct Code!");
            }
        }while(pass[i] == user[i]);
    }
}
```

Error received

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at Safe.actionPerformed(Safe.java:53)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what happens when you run it?

Comment: is there any error? what is expected behavior and what is the actual?

Comment: It gives this error when you run it(It not all the error)@Reimeus                           Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at Safe.actionPerformed(Safe.java:53)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] user = new int[5];
...
//pass[5] = 2;
```

Arrary indexes are 0 based, so index 5 is really the 6th entry which doesn't exist. So get rid of that statement.

Comment: Got rid of: pass[5] = 2; Now I can press b2, and b3 , but gives me the same error on CMD when I press 1.

Comment: @JoséAstrain, you removed the wrong statement. I commented the statement you need to remove.

Comment: Got rid of: pass[5] = 2; Now I can press b2, and b3 , but gives me the same error on CMD when I press b1.

Comment: So fix your logic error. The error message tell you which statement is causing the problem. Add some System.out.println(...) statements to see what the value of "I" is. Then figure out why the value of "I" is greater than 4. If you want to program you need to learn to debug your own logic. We have no idea what your logic is trying to do so we can't recommend a solution other than to say don' let the value of "I" be greater than 4.

Comment: By the way your label states: "enter a 6 digit combination". So if you really want 6 digits, then the size of your array needs to be 6 and you need to add back the statement you just commented out. Again, understand the "concept" of the answer given to you. Only you know exactly what your program is attempting to do.